# WP8.1 c# OneDrive API Code flow auth

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, universal, onedrive

I have an universal app which uses Token Flow for login. But the token is only grant for 1hour...which is not enough for a service.. So I want to set the auth method to "Code flow" .
I use this uri :

> https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?client_id={0}&scope={1}&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf&response_type=code&scope={1}&display=popup

I got a response from server: status = OK, but the response stream content is an html webpage. 
(user prompt for autorization) How can I do to show this ask for auth to user ? And get his response in WP8.1 ?

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, In Code flow you will get a ACCESS_CODE which again is used to get the ACCESS_TOKEN. Which again will be valid for one hour only.